# count(*) method raises error sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am trying to use the method `count(*)` but I always get an error.

here is the code

```
SQL> select c.cname,avg(o.ord_amt) avg_order_amt , count(*) no_of_order from customer c, orders o  group b
y orderno;
```

the error is:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I am pretty sure that the mistake is with `count(*)` method

I need to display the cname no_of_orders, avg_order_amt, where the middle column is total number of order and last is the average order amount for that customer.

Here is the table for customer and orders:

```
SQL> desc customer
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 CUSTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
CNAME                                              VARCHAR2(25)
CITY    
                                                 VARCHAR2(12)

SQL> desc orders
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 ORDERNO                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
ODATE                                     NOT NULL DATE
 CUSTNO                                             NUMBER(3)
 ORD_AMT                                            NUMBER(5)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+%22not+a+GROUP+BY+expression%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not work as mysql does that you can `group by` any column with grouping functions. The error it is giving you is because you are using these grouping functions with a column and you are not grouping by that column.

So, in order to your query work you have to do this:

```
select c.cname, 
       avg(o.ord_amt) avg_order_amt , 
       count(*) no_of_order 
  from customer c, 
       orders o  
 group by c.cname;
```

You are also missing a join. The way your query are you will get a `cartesian plan` between the `customer` and the `orders` table which means amount of registries in one times amount of registries on the other.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you're looking for here is:

```
select c.cname,
       avg(o.ord_amt) avg_order_amt ,
       count(*) no_of_order
from   customer c,
join   orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.cname;
```

I'm guessing on how to join those two tables, which you definitely need to do.

Comment: It seems very likely that the OP actually wants to do a `join` on these tables.  This would seem to be the right answer.